# How to use Typescript within existing requiresJS and angular1.2X project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, requirejs

How to use Typescript within existing requiresJS and angular1.2X project

I am somewhat of a noob to TypeScript. I looked for an answer everywhere and still have not found a solution that works.

I am trying to mix in TS into an existing project. I have run into some unforeseen problem.  The project uses RequireJS, Angular 1.2X… I have added all the typing I need but now I am not sure how to access the angular methods i.e. $q, $http…

**The way I usually do it in plain JS is below.**

```
define('common/services/ExampleService', [
    'js/app'
], function (app) {
    "use strict";

    app.factory('ExampleService', ['$q', '$timeout', '$http', '$log',
        function ($q, $timeout, $http, $log) {

            var someVars = "myApp";

            // service defines the public interface
            var service = {};
            service.example1 = example1;

            return service;

            ////////////////////////////////////////////

            function example1(someOtherVars) {
                $log.log('Example1 has started');

                // all kinds of logic...

                return whatINeed;
            }

        }
    ]);
});
```

**What I am trying to do in TypeScript:**

```
///<reference path='../../../app/typings/angular/angular.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='../../../app/typings/requirejs/require.d.ts'/>

define('common/services/ExampleService', [
    'js/app'
], (app) => {
    "use strict";

    app.factory('ExampleService',
        ['$log', '$q', 'RoleService',
            ($log, $q, $http) => {


                class Example1 {
                    private $log: any = $log;

                    constructor($log) {
                        $log.log('Example1 Constructor has started');
                        this.$log = $log;
                    }

                    exampleMethod() {
                        this.$log.log('exampleMethod has been called');

                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
});
```